# Making a portable and single .exe app multi language

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I currently developing a tool that must be portable and a single .exe, everything went fine until I needed to add localization support...

[image]

[image]

If I change the `Localizable` to `True`, set the `Language` and alter some label this happens:

[image]

And for now, my program is not single .exe anymore :(

Is there a way to compile or add multiple languages but stay with a single .exe ?

(I don't want to make several releases of my app in different languages, but if I need...)

Comment: You get satellite assemblies, they contain the culture specific resources.  This is not a problem, just copy them along with your EXE.  The operating system doesn't mind you copying two files instead of one.  If it is really important to get just one then that's not a problem either, most programmers name it setup.exe

Comment: Hi Mr. Passant, the problem is that I don't want to install the program, the tool is so simple that there is no need to. But I want to make available to lots of people. :)

Comment: I'll take a look at those satellite assemblies.